# Openshift 4 github issue on checkout

Tags: github, openshift, github-api

I've create a new project in openshift 4(console openshift, trial edition).
I'm trying to checkout my source from Github public repo .Meanwhile i'm getting this bellow error . 
Can someone help me on it ?

> admission webhook "validate.imagestream.update" does not support dry
>   run

regards

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are doing when you say you are "trying to checkout my source". Do you mean you are trying to do a source to image build or dockerfile build using your repo and pointing at your repo when setting this up from the web console, or perhaps when using command line?

Comment: The `us-west-2` OpenShift Online Starter cluster has been misconfigured for some time, roughly when you have created this question. Attempting to instantiate templates from the developer catalog would result such admission web hook errors. The issue is rectified by now, you should be able to deploy anything from the developer catalog.

Comment: trying to process the command oc process -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/siamaksade/openshift-cd-demo/ocp-4.1/cicd-template.yaml | oc create -f -

Comment: but i can create only one project...